# To show $\{(x,y,z) : x+z^2\sin(x+y) \ge z \}$ is closed in $\mathbb R^3$ by elementary methods

Tags: metric-spaces

How to show that the set $\{(x,y,z) : x+z^2\sin(x+y) \ge z \}$ , where $x,y,z$ each are from the set of real numbers , is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^3$ under usual Euclidean metric ? I know how to do it using continuous function $f(x,y,z)=x+z^2\sin(x+y) - z$ , but I want a more basic method using sequences or complement is open criteria etc. Please help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a general principle: When $f: \>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ is a continuous function then the set
$$A:=\{{\bf x}\in{\mathbb R}^n\>|\>f({\bf x})>0\}$$
is open, and the set
$$B:=\{{\bf x}\in{\mathbb R}^n\>|\>f({\bf x})\geq0\}$$
is closed.

*Proof.* Let ${\bf p}\in A$ and assume $f({\bf p})=:a>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at ${\bf p}$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of ${\bf p}$ such that
$$f({\bf x})>{a\over2}>0\qquad\forall {\bf x}\in U\ .$$
It follows that $U\subset A$, and since ${\bf p}\in A$ was arbitrary we can conclude that $A$ is open.

Since $-f$ is continuous as well it follows that the complement of $B$ is open, whence $B$ is closed.